# Showing progress bar through ajax request in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, ajax

I have created a vf page to upload `MultipleFiles` at a time. Now using AJAX request i am passing the file to Salesforce server and using `addEventListener` to show the progress bar, The issue here is the progress bar runs very fast within no time of span for small files and if i try to upload single file the progress bar it not even shown.

What may be the issue here.

Posting required part of AJAX call.

```
$.ajax({  
                            url: '/services/data/v45.0/sobjects/ContentVersion',  
                            data: JSON.stringify(conVer_object ),  
                            type: 'POST',  
                            processData: false,  
                            contentType: false,  
                            headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer {!$Api.Session_ID}', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},  
                            xhr: function(){  
                                var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();  
                                //Upload progress  
                                xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){  
                                    if (evt.lengthComputable) {  
                                        $('#progress_bar_container').css('display', 'block');  
                                        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;  
                                        console.log('percentComplete '+percentComplete );  
                                        var percentCompletex= percentComplete*100;  
                                        $('#percentText').html("Uploading. Please wait... "+Math.round(percentCompletex)+"%");  
                                        $('.progress').css('width', percentCompletex+ "%");  
                                        if(percentCompletex == 100){  
                                            $('#progress_bar_container').css('display', 'none');  
                                        }  
                                    }  
                                }, false);  
                                return xhr;  
                            },
```